# What happens to the wave function after applying the D'Alembert operator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, klein-gordon-equation

Is the result of applying the D'Alembert operator on a wave function always zero? Or are there exceptions?

Comment: First of all, zero would also be a result. Second of all, the function entering the massless Klein-Gordon equation (given by the D'Alembert operator) isn't a wave function but a field - classical or quantum field. If it were a wave function, the energy wouldn't be positively definite because there would be both solutions with $\exp(i\omega t)$ and $\exp(-i\omega t)$, positive and negative-frequency solutions, and energy would be unbounded from below. That's why "second quantization" is a must in relativistic theories and the function can't be an ordinary wave function.

Answer (score 2):

The Klein-Gordon equation for a free particle is $\Box\psi=-m^2\psi$, so that gives you your answer. It's zero only for massless fields.